# Fat Free Framework Routing System causes unexpected behavior

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

my routing code:

```php
F3::route('GET  @root: /', "\\Controller\\_App\\App_navigation->get_delegator");

F3::route('GET  @modul: /@module', "\\Controller\\@module->get_index");
F3::route('POST @modul',           "\\Controller\\@module->post_index");
F3::route('GET  @proses: /@module/@proc.ksd', "\\Controller\\@module->get_@proc");
F3::route('POST @proses',                     "\\Controller\\@module->post_@proc");


F3::route('GET  @submodul: /@module/@submodule', "\\Controller\\@module\\@submodule->get_index");
F3::route('POST @submodul',                      "\\Controller\\@module\\@submodule->post_index");

F3::route('GET  @proses2: /@module/@submodule/@proc.ksd', "\\Controller\\@module\\@submodule->get_@proc");
F3::route('POST @proses2',                                "\\Controller\\@module\\@submodule->post_@proc");
```

i was trying to access the `proses` route, and it's didn't match any. is this a unexpected behavior?

it's working when i disable the `submodul` and `proses2` routing name.

here's the screen shoot:
[image: 101 debugging mode~]

how to resolve this?

Comment: It seems that you override one routing rule with another. This particular address matches both rules and FFF takes the last rule and tries to call the assigned method. When you remove the other rules there is no conflict and the behaviour is like you expect it to be.

Comment: ahh, so i need to change the name? @george007

Comment: I will put it as an answer, because it got too long for just a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you've hit a [bug](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/commit/64277ffb27d781f0951b14ab756d545ae2f37690): `/@module/@submodule` took precedence order over `/@module/@proc.ksd` while it shouldn't.

If you download the latest `base.php` from the [edge repository](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core), your issue should be fixed.

Comment: So the rules are processed in the order they were declared?

Comment: No, they are processed in the reverse alphabetical order, with a lower precedence order for wildcards and tokens. You can view it in the [tests](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/a1866cae88d67774f45465ae202004fd60a89513/app/router.php#L218). The bug here was that the token name was also processed alphabetically while it shouldn't have been. So Kekesed hit the bug because `@submodule` starts with a S and `@proc` with a P.

Answer (score 0):

There is xfra35 answer which hopefully will fix your issue.

However in my opinion it is always going to be tricky when you have one route (in your example `/@module/@submodule`) which is more general than the other (`/@module/@proc.ksd`). In theory the engine should know that the latter is more strict than the former. Or that the former was declared later so it should be matched as the last one if other rules failed to match. But it may not always be the case.

If I were in your shoes, I would feel safer with some other solution. For example I would try to merge `@proses` and `@proses2` rules by putting all actions that are currently handled by main modules into dedicated submodules. So each module would only have a `get_index` method, while all other `get_*` methods would be in submodules. What do you think about this idea?